# excel vba: matrix value rearrangement

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

I have values which could be visualized as a matrix:

Example:

```
 5  0  0  11   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15  5  0   0  11  0  0  0  0  0  0
 3 11  5   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Colum sums would be:

```
23 16  5  11  11  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Total sum would be: 66

If the sums should be 6 for example in each column filling it up starting from the left side what would be the best way to distribute the numbers in the rows? In the end I would need something like this:

```
 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Colum sums would be:

```
 6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
```

Total sum would be: 66

Another example where the sum in the columns does not indicate even distribution:

```
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   2   0   0
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   0   0   0
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   0   0   0
```

Colum sums would be:

```
8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   2   0   0
```

Or another example with column value of 10:

```
4   4   4   4   4   4   2   0   0   0   0
4   4   4   4   4   4   2   0   0   0   0
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0
```

Colum sums would be:

```
10  10  10  10  10  10  6   0   0   0   0
```

What I have so far is this but it is not working:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(ColArray) - 1
    ExpColMaxDays = CalculatingManDays(ExpRows, ColArray(i))
    DiffManDays = ExpColMaxDays - MonthlyMax
    DevAmount = DiffManDays

    For j = 0 To UBound(RowArray)
        If DevAmount < 0 Then
            Do While DevAmount < 0
                cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i)).Value = cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i)).Value + 1
                cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i) + 1).Value = cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i) + 1).Value - 1
                DevAmount = DevAmount + 1
            Loop
        ElseIf DevAmount > 0 Then
            Do While DevAmount > 0
                cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i)).Value = cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i)).Value - 1
                cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i) + 1).Value = cells(RowArray(j), ColArray(i) + 1).Value + 1
                DevAmount = DevAmount - 1
            Loop
        End If

    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [excel vba: distribution of days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816399/excel-vba-distribution-of-days)

Comment: If sum is equal to `N` then put value `N/33` in each cell... If you want a different answer, then you'll have to formulate your question differently (i.e. more clearly).

Comment: @ Jean-Francois Corbett: I extended the question with more examples. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I do not find your new examples of any help.  This is partly because you give no before picture and partly because you still have not explained the distribution required.  In the first example, you have redistributed evenly across the entire matrix.  In the second two you have started the redistribution from top left with a value of 3 or 4.  Why 3 or 4?  What is the criteria for placing a lower value to the right and bottom of the valued area?  Why is this lower value 2? What does the function `CalculatingManDays` do?  What are the values `ExpColMaxDays` and `ExpRows`?

Comment: Hi Tony, The first matrix is the starting point. The function CalculatingManDays calculates all days I have in the current column. For the first column it would 23. Then I use this value and subtracted the allowed man days. If we stick to 6 I get 17 days. This means I have 17 days in the first column which are shifted to the next column. This value is saved in DevAmount. If DevAmount would be negative I would shift days from the next column and fill up the column until the allowed value is reached. This is was my algorithm does but at the end I have negative days in the last columns.

Comment: And then I would have to delete the negative days with the exact same number of positive days starting from the right column but is there another and faster way to distribute the days to avoid this situation?

Comment: 3 or 4 are merely partitions of 10. EXCEL VBA has no function to calculate this. But actually a fitting partition for a column with the constraint of 10 days and three rows would be something like this (4,4,2),(3,3,4),(5,5,0). I think calculating partitons in EXCEL VBA is extremly slow so I used another approach to achieve the sums which is not very fast either.

Comment: There are no criteria to assign a partition of the constraint to a particular row. So (3,3,4) or (4,3,3) or (3,4,3) would be equivalent.

Comment: RowArray and ColArray are necessary because I actually don't have a matrix. I have a sheet with lots of rows. The rows which consitute a matrix are for a certain person. It is easier and faster to access the cells in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to answer your question.

**Problem 1**

```
ExpColMaxDays = CalculatingManDays(ExpRows, ColArray(i))
```

What are `CalculatingManDays` and `ExpRows`?

**Problem 2**

What are `RowArray` and `ColArray`?  This seems a very complicated way of accessing a block of cells.  The following is easier unless there is some significance to this approach I am missing.

```
For RowCrnt = RowTop To RowBottom
  For ColCrnt = ColLeft to ColRight
    ... Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt) ...
```

**Problem 3**

If you really just want to distribute the values evenly across the rectangle, I suggest:

```
Sub Rearrange(RowTop As Long, ColLeft As Long, _
              RowBottom As Long, ColRight As Long)

  ' I assume the cell values are all integers without checking

  Dim CellValue As Long
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim NumCells As Long
  Dim Remainder As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim TotalValue As Long

  ' Calculate the total value 
  TotalValue = 0
  For RowCrnt = RowTop To RowBottom
    For ColCrnt = ColLeft To ColRight
      TotalValue = TotalValue + Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value
    Next
  Next

  ' Calculate the standard value for each cell and the remainder which
  ' will be distributed over the early cells
  NumCells = (RowBottom - RowTop + 1) * (ColRight - ColLeft + 1)
  CellValue = TotalValue / NumCells
  Remainder = TotalValue Mod NumCells

  For RowCrnt = RowTop To RowBottom
    For ColCrnt = ColLeft To ColRight
      If Remainder > 0 Then
        Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = CellValue + 1
        Remainder = Remainder - 1
      Else
        Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = CellValue
      End If
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```

**New section in response to respecification of problem**

By reading all your questions, I think I have an understanding of what you are attempting.  If my understanding is correct, I have had a similar problem.

One of my employers required us to keep records of the time spent on each activity type per project.  There were peaks (because we worked evenings and weekends to meet deadlines) and troughs (because we could not progress any of our projects) but the electronic system into which we entered our timesheets required we work not more than 37.5 hours per week.  The employer wanted the correct time recorded against each project and activity type so we had to spread the actual time out from peaks to troughs without moving time from one activity type or project to another.

The algorithm I used to spread out my time was as follows:

1. If the total time for the period was not the required multiple of 37.5, time was moved from the highest peaks or the deepest troughs to the first week of the next period.
2. Each cycle of the main loop would pick the week with the highest total.  If this total was less than or equal to 37.5 hours, the algorithm was finished.
3. The time recorded against each task (activity type and project) would be reduced so the new total was 37.5 and the new proportion of each task’s time to the total time for the week was as similar to the original proportion as possible.
4. The time subtracted from each task would be divided equally between the week before and the week after unless that week had already been correctly in which case the next uncorrected week in the same direction received the extra time.

My code does not perform step 1.  If the total time exceeds the permitted maximum, the problem is rejected as unsolvable.  The result of steps 2 to 4 is not the even spread of your examples because time is moved from a peak to the nearest trough and because time is not moved from row to row.  At the end of the process, all peaks have been removed and any remaining troughs can be anywhere within the period.  This gives a more realistic appearance and shows how time **might** have been allocated to tasks if the weekly maximum had not been exceeded.

For testing I have loaded each worksheet with a problem.  Cell A1 contains the maximum column value.  The matrix starts in cell B2 and continues to the first blank column and the first blank row.  The remainder of row 1 and column A may be used for headings if desired.  Columns to the right of the first blank column are not examined and may be used for comments.  The area below the matrix is used for the answer.

I have a control routine which loads data and calls the redistribution routine which does not know about the worksheets.

The redistribution routine accepts the maximum column value and the matrix as parameters and updates the matrix in situ.

In general I believe in giving the client what they have asked for.  I may gently push them in the direction of what I think they need but too often they must see the first version before they can understand why I suspect it may not be what they need.  Here I have broken my own rule and have given you what I think you need.  If you really do need an even distribution, this code can easily be adapted to create it but I want you to see a “realistic” distribution first.

I have placed comments within my code but the finer points of the algorithm may not be clear.  Try the code on a selection of redistribution problems.  If it looks about right I can give further explanations and detail parts of the algorithm that may require fine tuning.

I have not removed my diagnostic code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Control()

  ' For each worksheet

  '  * Validate and load maximum column value and matrix.
  '  * If maximum column value or matrix are faulty, output a message
  '    to below the matrix.
  '  * Call the redistribution algorithm.
  '  * Store result below the original matrix.

  Dim Addr As String
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColMatrixLast As Long
  Dim ErrMsg As String
  Dim Matrix() As Long
  Dim MatrixMaxColTotal As Long
  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowMatrixLast As Long
  Dim RowMsg As Long
  Dim TotalMatrix As Long
  Dim WSht As Worksheet

  For Each WSht In Worksheets
    ErrMsg = ""
    With WSht
      ' Load MaxCol
      If IsNumeric(.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
        MatrixMaxColTotal = Int(.Cells(1, 1).Value)  ' Ignore any decimal digits
        If MatrixMaxColTotal <= 0 Then
          ErrMsg = "Maximum column value (Cell A1) is not positive"
        End If
      Else
        ErrMsg = "Maximum column value (Cell A1) is not numeric"
      End If
      If ErrMsg = "" Then
        ' Find dimensions of matrix
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(2, 2).Value) Then
          ErrMsg = "Top left cell of matrix (Cell B2) is empty"
        Else
          Debug.Print .Name
          If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(2, 3).Value) Then
            ' Position to last non-blank cell in row 2 after B2
            ColMatrixLast = .Cells(2, 2).End(xlToRight).Column
          Else
            ' Cell C2 is blank
            ColMatrixLast = 2
          End If
          'Debug.Print ColMatrixLast
          If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(3, 2).Value) Then
            ' Position to last non-blank cell in column 2 after B2
            RowMatrixLast = .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
          Else
            ' Cell B3 is blank
            RowMatrixLast = 2
          End If
          'Debug.Print RowMatrixLast
          If ColMatrixLast = 2 Then
            ErrMsg = "Matrix must have at least two columns"
          End If
        End If
      End If
      If ErrMsg = "" Then
        ' Load matrix and validation as all numeric
        ReDim Matrix(1 To ColMatrixLast - 1, 1 To RowMatrixLast - 1)
        TotalMatrix = 0
        For RowCrnt = 2 To RowMatrixLast
          For ColCrnt = 2 To ColMatrixLast
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value) And _
               IsNumeric(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value) Then
              Matrix(ColCrnt - 1, RowCrnt - 1) = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value
              TotalMatrix = TotalMatrix + Matrix(ColCrnt - 1, RowCrnt - 1)
            Else
              ErrMsg = "Cell " & Replace(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Address, "$", "") & _
                       " is not numeric"
              Exit For
            End If
          Next
        Next
        If TotalMatrix > MatrixMaxColTotal * UBound(Matrix, 1) Then
          ErrMsg = "Matrix total (" & TotalMatrix & ") > Maximum column total x " & _
                   "Number of columns (" & MatrixMaxColTotal * UBound(Matrix, 1) & ")"
        End If
      End If
      RowMsg = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 2
      If ErrMsg = "" Then
        Call Redistribute(MatrixMaxColTotal, Matrix)
        ' Save answer
        For RowCrnt = 2 To RowMatrixLast
          For ColCrnt = 2 To ColMatrixLast
            .Cells(RowCrnt + RowMsg, ColCrnt).Value = Matrix(ColCrnt - 1, RowCrnt - 1)
          Next
        Next
      Else
        .Cells(RowMsg, "B").Value = "Error: " & ErrMsg
      End If
    End With
  Next

End Sub
Sub Redistribute(MaxColTotal As Long, Matrix() As Long)

  ' * Matrix is a two dimensional array.  A row specifies the time
  '   spent on a single task.  A column specifies the time spend
  '   during a single time period.  The nature of the tasks and the
  '   time periods is not known to this routine.
  ' * This routine uses rows 1 to N and columns 1 to M.  Row 0 and
  '   Column 0 could be used for headings such as task or period
  '   name without effecting this routine.
  ' * The time spent during each time period should not exceed
  '   MaxColTotal. The routine redistributes time so this is true.

  Dim FixedCol() As Boolean
  Dim InxColCrnt As Long
  Dim InxColMaxTotal As Long
  Dim InxColTgtLeft As Long
  Dim InxColTgtRight As Long
  Dim InxRowCrnt As Long
  Dim InxRowSorted As Long
  Dim InxTotalRowSorted() As Long
  Dim Lng As Long
  Dim TotalCol() As Long
  Dim TotalColCrnt As Long
  Dim TotalMatrix As Long
  Dim TotalRow() As Long
  Dim TotalRowCrnt As Long
  Dim TotalRowRedistribute() As Long

  Call DsplMatrix(Matrix)

  ReDim TotalCol(1 To UBound(Matrix, 1))
  ReDim FixedCol(1 To UBound(TotalCol))
  ReDim TotalRow(1 To UBound(Matrix, 2))
  ReDim InxTotalRowSorted(1 To UBound(TotalRow))
  ReDim TotalRowRedistribute(1 To UBound(TotalRow))

  ' Calculate totals per column and set all entries in FixedCol to False
  For InxColCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 1)
    TotalColCrnt = 0
    For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 2)
      TotalColCrnt = TotalColCrnt + Matrix(InxColCrnt, InxRowCrnt)
    Next
    TotalCol(InxColCrnt) = TotalColCrnt
    FixedCol(InxColCrnt) = False
  Next

  ' Calculate totals per row
  For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 2)
    TotalRowCrnt = 0
    For InxColCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 1)
      TotalRowCrnt = TotalRowCrnt + Matrix(InxColCrnt, InxRowCrnt)
    Next
    TotalRow(InxRowCrnt) = TotalRowCrnt
  Next
  ' Created sorted index into totals per row
  ' This sorted index allows rows to be processed in the total sequence
  For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(TotalRow)
    InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt) = InxRowCrnt
  Next
  InxRowCrnt = 1
  Do While InxRowCrnt < UBound(TotalRow)
    If TotalRow(InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt)) > _
                          TotalRow(InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt + 1)) Then
      Lng = InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt)
      InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt) = InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt + 1)
      InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt + 1) = Lng
      If InxRowCrnt > 1 Then
        InxRowCrnt = InxRowCrnt - 1
      Else
        InxRowCrnt = InxRowCrnt + 1
      End If
    Else
      InxRowCrnt = InxRowCrnt + 1
    End If
  Loop

  'For InxColCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 1)
  '  Debug.Print Right("  " & TotalCol(InxColCrnt), 3) & " ";
  'Next
  'Debug.Print
  'Debug.Print

  For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(TotalRow)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & TotalRow(InxRowCrnt), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(TotalRow)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  Do While True
    ' Find column with highest total
    InxColMaxTotal = 1
    TotalColCrnt = TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal)
    For InxColCrnt = 2 To UBound(TotalCol)
      If TotalColCrnt < TotalCol(InxColCrnt) Then
        TotalColCrnt = TotalCol(InxColCrnt)
        InxColMaxTotal = InxColCrnt
      End If
    Next
    If TotalColCrnt <= MaxColTotal Then
      ' Problem solved
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Find column to left, if any, to which
    ' surplus can be transferred
    InxColTgtLeft = 0
    For InxColCrnt = InxColMaxTotal - 1 To 1 Step -1
      If Not FixedCol(InxColCrnt) Then
        InxColTgtLeft = InxColCrnt
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    ' Find column to right, if any, to which
    ' surplus can be transferred
    InxColTgtRight = 0
    For InxColCrnt = InxColMaxTotal + 1 To UBound(TotalCol)
      If Not FixedCol(InxColCrnt) Then
        InxColTgtRight = InxColCrnt
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    If InxColTgtLeft = 0 And InxColTgtRight = 0 Then
      ' Problem unsolvable
      Call MsgBox("Redistribution impossible", vbCritical)
      Exit Sub
    End If
    If InxColTgtLeft = 0 Then
      ' There is no column to the left to which surplus can be
      ' redistributed.  Give its share to column on the right.
      InxColTgtLeft = InxColTgtRight
    End If
    If InxColTgtRight = 0 Then
      ' There is no column to the right to which surplus can be
      ' redistributed.  Give its share to column on the left.
      InxColTgtRight = InxColTgtLeft
    End If
    'Debug.Print InxColTgtLeft & " " & InxColMaxTotal & " " & InxColTgtRight
    ' Calculate new value for each row of the column with maximum total,
    ' Calculate the value to be redistributed and the new column total
    TotalColCrnt = TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal)
    For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(TotalRow)
      Lng = Round(Matrix(InxColMaxTotal, InxRowCrnt) * MaxColTotal / TotalColCrnt, 0)
      TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt) = Matrix(InxColMaxTotal, InxRowCrnt) - Lng
      Matrix(InxColMaxTotal, InxRowCrnt) = Lng
      TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) = TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) - TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt)
    Next
    If TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) > MaxColTotal Then
      ' The column has not be reduced by enough.
      ' subtract 1 from the value for rows with the smallest totals until
      ' the column total has been reduced to MaxColTotal
      For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(TotalRow)
        InxRowSorted = InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt)
        Matrix(InxColMaxTotal, InxRowCrnt) = Matrix(InxColMaxTotal, InxRowCrnt) - 1
        TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt) = TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt) + 1
        TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) = TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) - 1
        If TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) = MaxColTotal Then
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    ElseIf TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) < MaxColTotal Then
      ' The column has be reduced by too much.
      ' Add 1 to the value for rows with the largest totals until
      For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(TotalRow)
        InxRowSorted = InxTotalRowSorted(InxRowCrnt)
        Matrix(InxColMaxTotal, InxRowCrnt) = Matrix(InxColMaxTotal, InxRowCrnt) + 1
        TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt) = TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt) - 1
        TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) = TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) + 1
        If TotalCol(InxColMaxTotal) = MaxColTotal Then
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    End If
    ' The column which did have the hightest total has now beed fixed
    FixedCol(InxColMaxTotal) = True
    ' The values in TotalRowRedistribute must but added to the columns
    ' identified by InxColTgtLeft and InxColTgtRight
    For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(TotalRow)
      Lng = TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt) / 2
      Matrix(InxColTgtLeft, InxRowCrnt) = Matrix(InxColTgtLeft, InxRowCrnt) + Lng
      TotalCol(InxColTgtLeft) = TotalCol(InxColTgtLeft) + Lng
      Lng = TotalRowRedistribute(InxRowCrnt) - Lng
      Matrix(InxColTgtRight, InxRowCrnt) = Matrix(InxColTgtRight, InxRowCrnt) + Lng
      TotalCol(InxColTgtRight) = TotalCol(InxColTgtRight) + Lng
    Next
    Call DsplMatrix(Matrix)
  Loop

End Sub
Sub DsplMatrix(Matrix() As Long)

  Dim InxColCrnt As Long
  Dim InxRowCrnt As Long
  Dim TotalColCrnt As Long
  Dim TotalMatrix As Long
  Dim TotalRowCrnt As Long

  For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 2)
    TotalRowCrnt = 0
    For InxColCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 1)
      Debug.Print Right("  " & Matrix(InxColCrnt, InxRowCrnt), 3) & " ";
      TotalRowCrnt = TotalRowCrnt + Matrix(InxColCrnt, InxRowCrnt)
    Next
    Debug.Print " | " & Right("  " & TotalRowCrnt, 3)
  Next
  For InxColCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 1)
    Debug.Print "--- ";
  Next
  Debug.Print " | ---"

  TotalMatrix = 0
  For InxColCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 1)
    TotalColCrnt = 0
    For InxRowCrnt = 1 To UBound(Matrix, 2)
      TotalColCrnt = TotalColCrnt + Matrix(InxColCrnt, InxRowCrnt)
    Next
    Debug.Print Right("  " & TotalColCrnt, 3) & " ";
    TotalMatrix = TotalMatrix + TotalColCrnt
  Next
  Debug.Print " | " & Right("  " & TotalMatrix, 3)
  Debug.Print

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I used a variation from your code thx. Maybe the example was badly chosen to give the impression that the total sum has to be evenly distributed. But it should be distributed based on the value defined for each column. So if the value would be 8 or 10 then the values should be rearranged according to that leaving the right side with zero values.

Comment: I do not find your new examples of any help.  This is partly because you give no before picture and partly because you still have not explained the distribution required.  In the first example, you have redistributed evenly across the entire matrix.  In the second two you have started the redistribution from top left with a value of 3 or 4.  Why 3 or 4?  What is the criteria for placing a lower value to the right and bottom of the valued area?  Why is this lower value 2? What does the function `CalculatingManDays` do?  What are the values `ExpColMaxDays` and `ExpRows`?

Comment: I added the explanations above.

Comment: Was the new section I added to my answer helpful and if not why not?

Comment: Hello. Sorry about the delay. This looks very helpful and I think I can use it. Thanks for your efforts.